# array output not reading correctly

Tags: php, arrays, variables, sorting, directory

My issue is that one part displays file directory names and the other parts are supposed to be file counts for certain folders in those directories. right now it is listing the directory names but it is only doing a file count on the first directory and not on any of the others. i do realize that currently the code is for the counts under the In Que table header but if i get this figured out it makes it easier to use for the other categories.

but yes the issue is that i need it to grab file counts from all locations not just the first file path it finds.

**This is the code:**

```
<?php 
  if ($handle = opendir('Users/')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'somefile.php');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
        $i = 0; 
        $dir    = 'Users/';
        $files1 = scandir($dir);
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 4 and $i <= 4){
          $x++;
          $dir1 = 'Users/'.$files1[$x].'/uploaded/';

          if ($handle1 = opendir($dir1)) {
            while (($file1[$x] = readdir($handle1)) !== false){
              if (!in_array($file1[$x], array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir1.$file1[$x]))

                $i++;


            }
          }

          $file."\n" == $option; ?>
          <table border='1px' style="border:thin;" cols="3">
              <th>Employee</th>
              <th>In Que</th>
              <th>Incomplete</th>
              <th>Processed</th>
              <?php
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>";
              echo "$file\n";
              echo "</td>";
              echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."</td>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<br>";
              ?>
          </table>
          <?php

        }  
        // integer starts at 0 before counting
      }
    }
  } 
?>
```

Comment: In your `if` statements you should use `==` not `=`

Comment: @Vector That's actually perfectly fine for a statement like that. If opendir fails and does not assign $handle/$handle1, it won't execute the code.

Comment: @Ktech13: If you want accurate answers, please take the time to [format your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) properly and include the errors you're getting. That'll encourage more people to answer your question. Saying you have a deadline won't make anybody answer your question faster.

Comment: @AmalMurali: i never said do it for me as it is in my question i just would like some help figuring out why it is not outputting correctly.

Comment: +1 for Yoda conditions `while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))`

Comment: You have 7 levels of nested if/while. IMHO it's too much - try to do some refactoring, it we'll make you're code easier to follow/maintain.

Comment: @AmalMurali: i have trolled the internet on stuff like this but i have found nothing of use to my current issue so i decided to post it here to see if another could point out something that i was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing $x as soon as you enter loop so you will miss `$files1[1]` to start with...
If I am not misinterpreting this you are can get that achieved by couple loops.

```
$count = 0;
    $folders = @scandir('Users');  
    foreach($folders as $item){
        if (preg_match("/.*\.php$/",$item)) continue;
        if (is_dir("Users/$item")){
            $target_folders = @scandir("Users/$item/uploaded/");
            foreach($target_folders as $target_item){
                if ((!preg_match("/^[.]/",$target_item)) || (!is_dir("Users/$item/uploaded/$target_item"))) $count++;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code is throwing a syntax error on the last if statement

Comment: Was just missing a )) and a ; :D

Comment: output should be

techtesting 9
tech 0
Ktech 9

but i am getting 

techtesting 25
tech 25
Ktech 25

Comment: i need something along the lines of a foreach $item count=0 so the count starts over when it goes from techtesting to tech to Ktech